# aao.exe *32 in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, security, anti-virus

I don't know what I did but a program shows up on my computer named "Win 7 Home Security - Unregistred Version". It scans my computer for viruses. But something is not right so I think it is not what it's title says. My applications flash with a high frequency and I can't end process it's task. I have 3 aao.exe *32 in my task manager. I don't know what to do with it.

It says that you must purchase the application. When I clicked on it, a website showed up just like microsoft but it was not microsoft.com. I am certain that is is a virus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a fake anti-virus program; [you should get rid of it](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/remove-win-7-internet-security-2011).

The `*32` just means that it's a 32-bit process on your 64-bit system; there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I know it is fake but do you know how to remove it?

Comment: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/remove-win-7-internet-security-2011

Comment: Thank you SLaks, I removed it but now I want to start my microsoft essential but it says "The specified service does not exist as an istalled service". How can I start it?

Comment: Try re-installing it.

Comment: When I want to install it, it says that it is already installed.

Comment: Try un-installing it.